# Type error in user code while making a neural network using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am getting a type error in user code when I try to train a neural network model. I'm relatively new to deep learning so I tried this problem. Please let me know how to fix this and please let me know if there are some methods to improve accuracy

#### Problem statement:

I used a medical data set to determine the patient priority aka triaging in case of a lack of resources in a hospital. The data set initially had integer type data and object type data.

#### Data used:

- The training features have 5240 rows and 19 columns.
- The training output labels have 5240 rows and 5 columns

I used the get_dummies function from pandas to perform one hot encoding. The categorical data columns which  were encoded are there:

- residence type: urban or rural
- smoking status: smokes, formerly smoked, never smoked

and in the output:

```
trige:
red 
orange
yellow 
green
```

red being critical and green being regular

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6962 entries, 0 to 6961
Data columns (total 18 columns):
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6551 entries, 0 to 6961
Data columns (total 14 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   age                6551 non-null   float64
 1   gender             6551 non-null   float64
 2   chest pain type    6551 non-null   float64
 3   blood pressure     6551 non-null   float64
 4   cholesterol        6551 non-null   float64
 5   max heart rate     6551 non-null   float64
 6   exercise angina    6551 non-null   float64
 7   plasma glucose     6551 non-null   float64
 8   skin_thickness     6551 non-null   float64
 9   insulin            6551 non-null   float64
 10  bmi                6551 non-null   float64
 11  diabetes_pedigree  6551 non-null   float64
 12  hypertension       6551 non-null   float64
 13  heart_disease      6551 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(14)
memory usage: 767.7 KB
```

This is the code I used

```py
df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Residence_type','smoking_status','triage'])

#input features
x_tot=df_encoded.drop(['triage_orange','triage_red','triage_yellow','triage_green','Unnamed: 0'])

#output labels
out_cols=["triage_red", "triage_orange","triage_yellow","triage_green"]
y_tot=df_encoded[out_cols]

#train test split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_tot, y_tot, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#model training
model = Sequential([Dense(units = 18, activation = 'relu'),
                    Dense(units = 10, activation = 'relu'),
                    Dense(units = 4 , activation = 'softmax'),
                    ])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'], loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy)

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=40,validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
```

Error:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-61-c83a17ffabdc> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=40)
      2 # loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
      3 # print("Test Loss:", loss)
      4 # print("Test Accuracy:", accuracy)

1 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

TypeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1151, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1209, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py", line 277, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 161, in __call__
        return losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/losses_utils.py", line 328, in compute_weighted_loss
        losses = tf.convert_to_tensor(losses)

    TypeError: Failed to convert elements of <keras.src.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x7aa434443130> to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.
```

Comment: Are your labels integers 0, 1, 2?

Comment: No, they aren't they are one hot encoded  to unsigned integers which are 0 and 1

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the error trace as *text*, *not* as screenshot; see how to create a [mre].

Comment: The sparse categorical cross-entropy loss expects integer labels, in your case 0, 1, 2, and 3.